# Numpy data types (dtype.char)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array where `arr.dtype.char = d`. [Numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) indicate that `d` represents a double-precision floating-point number. If I want this array simply as an integer I can change the datatype using something like `arr.astype('int64')`. However this doesn't change the value given by `arr.dtype.char`.

I don't understand what is going on here. A module I am using doesn't support data type `d`. How do I change it? The module supports data types `B`, `H`, `h`, `f`, what are each of these used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually to change the arr datatype, you have to write:

```
arr_int = arr.astype('int64')
```

As for the data types, read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

Edit:
As noted in the comments by Sven Marnach, `arr.astype('int64')` returns a copy of the array. It doesn't change arr itself at all.

Comment: As noted in the question this changes `arr.dtype` but does not `arr.dtype.char = d`.

Comment: @JohnCrow it should. it works for me. what is the output of `arr.astype(np.int).dtype.char`?

Comment: @JohnCrow To be a bit more explicit, `arr.astype('int64')` returns a _new view_ into `arr`.  It doesn't change `arr` itself at all.

Comment: @weeCoder Note that `arr.astype(np.int)` is platform-dependent.  On a 32 bit platform, it won't work as expected.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I agree.

Comment: Actually, `astype()` even returns a copy of the array, not a new view into the same data (which wouldn't work, since data representation for different dtypes is different).

Comment: @weeCoder Cheers! It seems i just wasn't 'saving' the change. Also FYI the link in your answer is wrong.

Comment: @JohnCrow Good. Oh my bad. Now it's okay.